# PHP foreach display country name in API Call

Tags: php, curl, foreach

I am using Resellers Panel API for the following question. ([documentation](https://cp.resellerspanel.com/downloads/ResellersPanelAPI.pdf))

I have a Curl script with a foreach within it. That is getting the country list from the resellers panel api.

```
function getCountries() {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "myapiurl");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $final = curl_exec($ch);
    $result = explode(" ", $final);

        echo '<select>';
        foreach ($result as $country => $name) {
            echo '<option>'.$country. '</option>';
        }

        echo '</select>';

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

The above code is resulting in:

```
<select> 
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>
```

This continues for all 114 countries listed. I didn't feel the need to place all 114 options here.

It appears as if the foreach is just counting each result from the curl and posting that in the select. How would I get this to actually echo out the country name rather than just count?

In raw form the API results just like so: For example, only one country is listed.

```
<ampa>
  <command>"0"
  <error_code>0</error_code>
  <countries>
    <n0>
      <name>Afghanistan</name>
      <iso2>AF</iso2>
      <phone_code>93</phone_code>
    </n0>
 </countries>
</ampa>
```

**UPDATE**

I tried `echo '<option value="'.$country.'">'.$name. '</option>';` and it resulted in the following:

```
<option value="0">
0
0
56000


        Afghanistan
        AF
        93


        Albania
        AL
        355


        Algeria
        DZ
        213


        American</option>
```

When I echo out $final, I receive this (in short):

```
0 0 56000 Afghanistan AF 93 Albania AL 355 Algeria DZ 213 American Samoa AS 684 Andorra AD 376 Angola AO 244 Anguilla AI 1 Antarctica AQ 672 AG 1 Argentina AR 54 Armenia AM 374 Aruba AW 297 Australia AU 61 Austria AT 1 0 0.2 43
```

And I would like to be able to echo out the country name in a select using a foreach statement.

ex:

```
<select>
 <option>United States</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That's not "count". The loop `foreach ($result as $country => $name) {` define that `$country` is the key, and `$name` is the value, that's why you are getting the index instead of the country name. Try `echo '<option value="'.$country.'">'.$name. '</option>';`

Comment: @TrungDQ that should be an answer. If you can explain why this is so **and** put in a link to mdn that would be great.

Comment: Mitch Evans , Could you give us a small piece of the text you get when you `echo $final`, and exactly how you would like to extract the data from it? Is it just a list of names, then what TrungDQ said is correct; `foreach($array AS $key=>$value)`. When you created the array you automatically assigned the keys from 0..n. If it is an XML file, then you may want to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to handle it.

Comment: @Mitch Evans write a function that splits the string into the array you want. You could probably do this pretty easily with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) if you know regex.

Comment: @HorseSMith - Did you see where I showed the raw form of the call before I put it into the foreach section?

Comment: Try: `preg_match_all(' ([a-zA-Z ]+?) [A-Z]{2} [0-9]+', $final, $matches);`, and then tell me what you get when you; `print_r($matches);`. Also, what are you supposed to do with `<option>United States</option>`? You don't give it any value.

Comment: @HorseSMith -- I get this: `Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '[' in D:\Hosting\11605285\html\assets\functions\hosting-functions.php on line 36` And I figured I would just add the same value as the displayed value once I get everything working! Ex: `<option value="United States">United States</option>`

Comment: `preg_match_all('/ ([a-zA-Z ]+?) [A-Z]{2} [0-9]+/', $final, $matches);`, that should fix it.

Comment: `
        Array
(
    [0] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [1] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

)
      ` is exactly what I receive

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40084/discussion-between-horse-smith-and-mitch-evans)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are exploding the string wrongly. Your are explode " ", empty string. but base on you return, i assume it was in XML node format. if you print out everything, it shows all the node information, but you are only require `<name>Afghanistan</name>` . Try to user `simplexml_load_string`, is a php function. Example in [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php).
So you can directly access to `name` node. Hope this help.

Comment: This may be more universal as opposed to answer two... I will check this out later tonight when I have time and possibly accept this as an answer.

Comment: Base on your API output, it shows that it is in XML format. Every none  is "tagged" and all you need to do is to get them into array, indexed by the node name. try to update your code if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "myapiurl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
# curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, POST);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$final = curl_exec($ch);

$domd = new DOMDocument();
$domd->loadXML($final);
$countries = $domd->getElementsByTagName('countries')->item(0)->childNodes;

echo '<select>';

foreach($countries AS $country){
    // the following is just to make sure we only get tags with the name "n\d+"
    if(preg_match('/n\d+/', $country->tagName)){
        $name = $country->getElementsByTagName('name');
        // to make sure there's a sub-tag named "name"
        if($name->length!=1) continue;
        echo '<option value="'.$country->tagName.'">'
        .$name->item(0)->nodeValue.'</option>';
    }
}

echo '</select>';
```

The curl_setopt line I commented out is pretty pointless and should give you a warning or error. POST is supposed to be a long string with post values, muhc like get values in an url. variable1=value1&variable2=value2&variable3=value3 etc. This is used to send specific "calls" to the server, perhaps so it give you different output, like for example just some few countries instead of all.

You can also use simplexml as Steven suggested. It's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: This works for getting the countries name and formatting it into a nice select option. However, it doesn't work for anything else like getting my plan names, customer information, or even getting my data centers. I need something more universal where all I have to change is a few things to get it to work. I'm tired of fighting this, I want a nice easy solution.

Comment: Try to understand the code and do whatever changes you need. If you want the "iso2"-tag's value then just do the same as I did with the "name"-tag.